# Can JSON schemas specify cross-field constraints?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

Lets say I have a simple contact database with a "Last Called" history, stored in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) format:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {"id": 10001, "name": "Fred"},
    {"id": 10006, "name": "Helen"},
    {"id": 10009, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 10030, "name": "Tara"},
    {"id": 10101, "name": "Jason"}
  ],
  "history": [
    {"id": 10006, "time": 1513567986},
    {"id": 10001, "time": 1513567243},
    {"id": 10101, "time": 1513566511},
    {"id": 10030, "time": 1513565012},
    {"id": 10006, "time": 1513562390}
  ]
}
```

I'd like to thoroughly validate this. Specifying the overall structure (e.g. make sure that each `contact` has both a numeric `id` and a string `name`) and value limitations (e.g. `id`s are numbers between 10000 and 99999) is straightforward. However, I'd like to implement more sophisticated checks, e.g.:

- Each `contacts` object has a unique `id` value
- Each `history` object's `id` value matches a `contact`'s `id' value

Can these constraints be specified using a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/)? (Note that the solution shouldn't depend on the two `id` fields being relatively close to each other in the structure; in a complete application they might each be a couple of levels deep in separate value trees.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this with JSON Schema. You can check for unique items in an array, but not the object values.

You may have already thought of this, the option would be to loop through the object keys and validate it by hand. For example, you can add the `id`s to a Set and compare the set size and array length.